# Creating a custom view style in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

We're currently building a sharepoint 2013 site but the need to create a custom view style has now become apparent. When viewing documents, the following features would be ideal:

- The ability to specify conditional colour values based off dropdown
  values.
- The ability to add additional styles to a list view - table padding
  etc.
- The ability to show additional content to a list view - table headings
  etc.

As a short term solution we've enabled a thumbnail image to be chosen when a document is added, but this is less than ideal - especially for the client.

We can't seem to find any documentation on how to create a custom view style anywhere so your knowledge would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S I should note that:

- We only have access to Sharepoint Designer 2013 and not 2010.
- We cannot use any external JS libaries.

Comment: This is a poor question. You want someone to code that up for you? Or have you tried something that doesn't work? Have you search google ? Read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hi Max, I've now edited my question to be more informative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no poor or stupid questions. But styling in SharePoint is a wide area. The prefered way for styling and customizing is JSLink, here is a basic tutorial that might help:
http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html